# Opimzation of cost based Cypher query

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

For the following relationships, there are costs between nodes.

```
CREATE (n:STATION {name: 'BA'});
CREATE (n:STATION {name: 'BB'});
CREATE (n:STATION {name: 'BC'});
CREATE (n:STATION {name: 'BD'});

MATCH (a:STATION {name: 'BA'}),
      (b:STATION {name: 'BB'})
MERGE (a)-[:ROUTE {route: 1, cost: 10}]->(b)
MERGE (b)-[:ROUTE {route: 1, cost: 10}]->(a);

MATCH (a:STATION {name: 'BA'}),
      (b:STATION {name: 'BC'})
MERGE (a)-[:ROUTE {route: 2, cost: 3}]->(b)
MERGE (a)-[:ROUTE {route: 3, cost: 4}]->(b)
MERGE (b)-[:ROUTE {route: 2, cost: 3}]->(a)
MERGE (b)-[:ROUTE {route: 3, cost: 4}]->(a);

MATCH (a:STATION {name: 'BC'}),
      (b:STATION {name: 'BB'})
MERGE (a)-[:ROUTE {route: 2, cost: 2}]->(b)
MERGE (a)-[:ROUTE {route: 3, cost: 3}]->(b)
MERGE (b)-[:ROUTE {route: 2, cost: 2}]->(a)
MERGE (b)-[:ROUTE {route: 3, cost: 3}]->(a);

MATCH (a:STATION {name: 'BD'}),
      (b:STATION {name: 'BB'})
MERGE (a)-[:ROUTE {route: 4, cost: 2}]->(b)
MERGE (b)-[:ROUTE {route: 4, cost: 2}]->(a);
```

[image]

When I query by using [*..10], it can return correct result. But it is slow as it needs to search for many possibilities.

```
MATCH p=((a:STATION {name: 'BA'})-[*..10]->(b:STATION {name: 'BB'}))
WHERE NONE (n IN nodes(p) 
            WHERE size(filter(x IN nodes(p) 
                              WHERE n = x))> 1) 
WITH reduce(acc=[], r in rels(p) | 
  CASE
    WHEN size(acc) > 0 and last(acc) = r.route THEN acc 
    ELSE acc + r.route
  END) as reducedRoutes,
reduce(cost=0, r in rels(p) | cost + r.cost) as routecost
WHERE NONE (n IN reducedRoutes 
            WHERE size(filter(x IN reducedRoutes 
                              WHERE n = x))> 1) 
RETURN reducedRoutes, routecost, size(reducedRoutes) as len
ORDER BY routecost ASC, len ASC
```

Result:

```
╒═════════════╤═════════╤═══╕
│reducedRoutes│routecost│len│
╞═════════════╪═════════╪═══╡
│[2]          │5        │1  │
├─────────────┼─────────┼───┤
│[3, 2]       │6        │2  │
├─────────────┼─────────┼───┤
│[2, 3]       │6        │2  │
├─────────────┼─────────┼───┤
│[3]          │7        │1  │
├─────────────┼─────────┼───┤
│[1]          │10       │1  │
└─────────────┴─────────┴───┘
```

When I query by using allshortestpaths, it returns wrong result as I do not expect this kind of shortest path.

```
MATCH p=allshortestpaths((a:STATION {name: 'BA'})-[*]->(b:STATION {name: 'BB'}))
WHERE NONE (n IN nodes(p) 
            WHERE size(filter(x IN nodes(p) 
                              WHERE n = x))> 1) 
WITH reduce(acc=[], r in rels(p) | 
  CASE
    WHEN size(acc) > 0 and last(acc) = r.route THEN acc 
    ELSE acc + r.route
  END) as reducedRoutes,
reduce(cost=0, r in rels(p) | cost + r.cost) as routecost
WHERE NONE (n IN reducedRoutes 
            WHERE size(filter(x IN reducedRoutes 
                              WHERE n = x))> 1) 
RETURN reducedRoutes, routecost, size(reducedRoutes) as len
ORDER BY routecost ASC, len ASC
```

Result:

```
╒═════════════╤═════════╤═══╕
│reducedRoutes│routecost│len│
╞═════════════╪═════════╪═══╡
│[1]          │10       │1  │
└─────────────┴─────────┴───┘
```

I would like to ask, is there any way to perform cost based search with better performance written in Cypher?

Also, is there any other better solution other than Neo4j?

Comment: I can see there is Dijkstra algorithm built in that allows using path cost, but how to use it with cypher?

Comment: If there is more routes, the time needed increased exponentially.

Comment: Of course I can use the RESTful api like POST http:/localhost:7474/db/data/node/12/paths

`{
  "to" : "9",
  "cost_property" : "cost",
  "default_cost": 200,
  "relationships" : {
    "type" : "ROUTE",
    "direction" : "out"
  },
  "algorithm" : "dijkstra"
}`

to get all the paths and query again in Cypher. But in this case, I cannot figure out the second or the third shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

We use pseudo-uninion in such a case (`rank` can be adjusted to the amount of data):

```
UNWIND RANGE(0,3) AS rank
  MATCH (from: STATION {name:"BA"})
  MATCH (to: STATION {name:"BB"})
  WITH from, to, rank
    MATCH path = allShortestPaths( (from)-[:ROUTE*]->(to) )
      WHERE LENGTH(path)>rank
    UNWIND NODES(path) AS rn
    WITH rank, path, COLLECT(DISTINCT rn) AS rns
      WHERE SIZE(rns)=SIZE(NODES(path))
RETURN DISTINCT rank, 
       path, 
       REDUCE(c = 0, r IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) | c+r.cost) AS routecost
ORDER BY routecost
```

Comment: It seems like it is also using the way of exhaustive search. [:ROUTE*] will make the query infinitely long.